# API rest response code for not handle endpoint

Tags: rest, api, http-status-codes, restful-architecture

I have

> /rest/drink/categories?alcohol=true

which is return 200 status code with list of drink categories that have alcohol in it, e.g.

> 200 ['wine','beer']

I wonder what status code should I use, if a user hit a none handled path like below

> /rest/drink

or

> /rest/drink?alcohol=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[404 - Not found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) if the URL does not exist,
[400 - Bad request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_400) if the URL exists but the request parameter is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Http has status for such conditions.

`4XX` defines the error is from client side and needs a change.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) says

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for situations in which the client seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server should include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. These status codes are applicable to any request method. User agents should display any included entity to the user.[31]

For the condition where it is mentioned, its ideal to use `404 - Not Found` or `400 - Bad Request`

[This](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) gives list of all the status codes and appropriate explanation.

[W3Org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)
defined the specifications for these.